# ngModel remove the Checked status of checkbox automatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I am using Angular to validate a checkbox and using `ng-model` for that:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="news1" value="news1" ng-model="news" <c:if test="${xxxx == yes'}">checked="checked"></c:if>>
<label ng-click="news1();"></label>
```

When the page where the checkbox is being embedded is called via a link which passes the status of the news1 (yes).. I mean if the user is laready registered for news1 or not. If it's so, the checkbox should be checked dynamically otherwise it's unchecked.

The problem is that when I use/add: `ng-model="news1"` as attribute in the checkbox, it doesn't work correctly. The checkbox is checked for seconds and it become unchecked suddenly.

In the controller I'm having the following function to change the status of the checkbox after the page has been loaded, so that the user can check and/or uncheck the checkbox:

```
$scope.news1 = function (){
    if(!$scope.news1){
        $scope.news1 = !$scope.news1;
    } else{
        $scope.news1 = !$scope.news1;
    }
};
```

The question, how can fix this so that the Checkbox keeps being checked when the status for news1 in the link is: yes. 
How can I prevent angular from setting the checkbox to unchecked automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: You are using the same name for a property and a function name. Rename both to be more descriptive and that'll solve your problem.

Comment: use either value or ng-model, not both.

Comment: None of them did help... when I check the generated code in chrome I see that angular adds the following the the checkbox as value in a attribute class calss="check-filialen ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.. it's `ng-init="xxxxx=true"`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="news1" value="news1" ng-model="news" <c:if test="${xxxx == yes'}"> ng-init="news=true"></c:if>>
```

Thanks!